# Grabbing from Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am trying to create a variable that grabs the type_name from an array.

Here is my array.

```
var customIcons = {
        ItemI: {
            icon: 'http://...'
            type_name: 'East'
        },
        ItemII: {
            icon: 'http://...'
            type_name: 'West'
        },
        ItemIII: {
            icon: 'https:...'
            type_name: 'North'

        },
        question: {
            icon: 'https:...'
            type_name: 'South'

        }
```

}

Here is the variable I am trying to create.  I know the php is passing in correctly, but I do not know why it is not grabbing the appropriate type_name from the array:

```
   var buttonText= customIcons[<?php echo $type; ?>].type_name;
```

I am getting a cannot read property 'type_name' of undefined when I try to use the variable.

Sincere thanks for any help! It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's because it's not an array, it's a JSON object.  You'll need to use a JSON parse.

Comment: Yes, an object that is in JSOn format.  Will want to use `JSON.parse(text[, reviver])` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: you are missing a comma after first field i.e.  icon: {'http://...' ,type_name: 'East'}

Comment: @Scott: Is it just me, or is that not JSON? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation

Comment: I am interested in the answer as well. Based on your reference question (@Qantas), it seems the single vs double quotes is the defining thing for this example.

Comment: I was slightly wrong, semantics. You have an Object. Not an array, nor a JSON object (because you don't have quotes around your keys, but easily could). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite it to

```
   var buttonText= customIcons['<?php echo $type; ?>'].type_name;
```

See the `' '` around `<?php ?>`, else it is parsed as a js variable

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that was it. I don't know how I missed it, I had a similar line with the quotes right above it.

Comment: @ambe5960 remember (so you don't fall in the same trap again) `[]` = Array, `{}` = Object

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the quotes.
`var buttonText= customIcons['<?php echo $type; ?>'].type_name;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about PHP but here is what is wrong

Your JSON : You have a missing comma

```
var customIcons = {
        item1: {
            icon: 'http://...',
            type_name: 'East'
        },
        item2: {
            icon: 'http://...',
            type_name: 'West'
        },
        item3: {
            icon: 'https:...',
            type_name: 'North'

        },
        question: {
            icon: 'https:...',
            type_name: 'South'

        }
};

console.log(customIcons.item1.icon);
```

Then Your JSON structure is not ideal

It should have been

```
var customIcons = [


           {
                id:"item1",
                icon: 'http://...',
                type_name: 'East'
            },
            {
                id:"item2",
                icon: 'http://...',
                type_name: 'West'
            },
            item: {
                id:"item3",
                icon: 'https:...',
                type_name: 'North'

            },
           {
                id:"item4",  
                icon: 'https:...',
                type_name: 'South'

            }
]

Then you can parse this easily using for loop
```